# Out of dnodes (0.000000s)

Tags: tdengine

The TDengine fails to CREATE a DATABASE. CREATE DATABASE power KEEP 365 DURATION 10 BUFFER 16 WAL_LEVEL 1;

This error occurs when I try to create a database. How do I fix it，I can fix it.If you have similar problems, please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, TDengine will support dnodes number same as the number of current machine's CPU cores by default. If you already create a few databases used all of dnodes then you can't create more database. But you can modify the configuration file's supportVnodes to increase its limitation.